# How to terminate a Keep-Alive connection?

Tags: apache2

I'm writing a PHP script using the Twitter API which requires a Keep-Alive connection.

But in order to be able to conduct some tests, I need to terminate the K-A connection without having to do a full `sudo service apache2 restart`.

How can I do it?

---

**EDIT**

These are some extra details to avoid confusion: 
I am **not** asking about deactivating the K-A function altogether from Apache.   All I need is a way to ask the server to terminate its *current* Keep-Alive connection with the Twitter server so that, for example, I can update the API call with more information and relaunch the connection again.

Right now, I just restart the whole server, which isn't that elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and change

```
KeepAlive On -> KeepAlive Off
```

or if there is no KeepAlive option already simply add:

```
KeepAlive Off
```

And restart your apache2 to take effect.

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question, but this is NOT what I'm looking for as shown in the question details.

Comment: Ok your question is not that clear. IMO, you'd better update it in order to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: I just added more details. I hope this helps.